# How can I detect ActiveX support?

Tags: c#, javascript, activex, modernizr

I know that `Modernizr` hasn't got a built-in test for `ActiveX` and detecting ActiveX support for `IE` gets [complicated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after IE11 (look at Silverlight version detection code).

Is there any workaround for detecting ActiveX support all versions of IE and other browsers? Also I have to control this server-side too and `Request.Browser.ActiveXControls` returns false on IE11 ([This issue has been reported Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/82e37fa9-4e0a-4428-986f-d8189f4d8e7c/)).

Comment: Just assume you cannot use ActiveX. Because if you don't, you are going to use an IE-only feature which is an incredibly bad idea in any case.

Comment: I know that and I want to get rid of ActiveX but I have to use it for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script for client-side and if you save it to element, you can access it via server-side.

```
function IsActiveXSupported() {
    var isSupported = false;

    if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        return true;
    }

    if("ActiveXObject" in window) {
        return true;
    }

    try {
        var xmlDom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        isSupported = true;
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.name === "TypeError" || e.name === "Error") {
            isSupported = true;
        }
    }

    return isSupported;
}
```

Comment: *"you can access it via server-side"* - uhhhh?!

Comment: i know that it is a bad idea but if you save its return value in a hiddenfield, then you can access it, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can test if `typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined'`.

Note that you MUST check `typeof`, this is what I got in IE11 (which does not support ActiveX anymore):

```
>>> window.ActiveXObject
undefined
>>> typeof window.ActiveXObject
"undefined"
>>> typeof window.ActiveXObject === 'undefined'
true
>>> window.ActiveXObject === undefined
false
```

In IE10 mode and below:

```
>>> typeof window.ActiveXObject
"function"
```

So that check *will* let you find out if you can use `ActiveXObject(..)` to create a new ActiveX object.

Comment: typeof window.ActiveXObject returns "undefined" on ActiveX enabled IE11 and Chrome which doesn't support ActiveX.

Comment: It supports. I run ActiveX on IE11. If you want to read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/14/metro-style-browsing-and-plug-in-free-html5.aspx

Comment: Yes, @ogun is right. `typeof` returns undefined, but actually IE11 DOES support ActiveX, I've tested it

Answer (score 0):

Update on @ogun's code:

```
function def( o ) { return CS.undefined !== typeof o; }

function IsActiveXSupported() {
    try {
        // Test if it should be supported
        if ( def( window.ActiveXObject ) || ( "ActiveXObject" in window ) ) {
            // Test if it is really supported
            var start = performance.now();
            var xmlDom = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            var elapsed = performance.now() - start;
            return true;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // When active X controls are possible, but disabled, an exception will be thrown.
    }
    return false;
}
```

Reasons for the update:  When ActiveX is possible, but disabled, an exception will be thrown. The original code would indicate this as 'enabled'. Don't call this function repeatedly, as it is not very fast. Tested on IE11, current Firefox and Chrome. (You can remove the  performance measuring.)

Answer (score -1):

If all else fails, you can fall back to a try-catch block:

```
try {
    var x = new ActiveXObject("...");
    // this particular ActiveX Control is supported
}
catch (error) {
    // it's not supported
}
```

Comment: If I use this method, I have to check spesific ActiveX control.

Comment: Not really. Just test an active x control that is commonly supported. If it throws an exception, set a global variable to false. If no exception is thrown, set the global flag to true.

Comment: thanks! i have used your try-catch block and i wrote general method. i will add this as an aswer. please check it.